# Deleted Draft Envelopes have inaccurate status

Tags: docusignapi

Occasionally our application will create Draft Envelopes in DocuSign which are then deleted by an end user in the DocuSign UI without ever being sent.

When our application uses the SOAP API call [RequestStatusCodes](https://www.docusign.com/p/APIGuide/APIGuide.htm#Status%20and%20Managing%20Group/RequestStatusCodes.htm%3FTocPath%3DDocuSign%2520Service%2520API%2520Information%7CStatus%2520and%2520Managing%2520Function%2520Group%7C_____24)() to query created envelopes by Envelope ID we still get a status of 'Created' for the deleted envelope. This is a problem because our system maintains a lock on documents after they are upload to DocuSign until they reach a terminal state (Deleted, Voided, Completed).

Is it expected that an Envelope deleted in DocuSign while in the Draft/Created state will never have its status updated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DocuSign support has informed me that this is expected behavior.