# No webhook calls for deleted draft envelopes

Tags: docusignapi

I saw this question [Deleted Draft Envelopes have inaccurate status](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41837666/deleted-draft-envelopes-have-inaccurate-status) about **deleted drafts**, but I wanted to check if that's also true for webhooks.

If I create **Draft Envelope** in DocuSign from my application, and then user **deletes** that Envelope in DocuSign, will any webhook event fire?

These are the event notifications that I have specified when Draft Envelope is created or Envelope is sent:

```
{
  "eventNotification": {
    "envelopeEvents": [
      { "envelopeEventStatusCode": "completed" },
      { "envelopeEventStatusCode": "declined"  },
      { "envelopeEventStatusCode": "voided"    }
    ]
  }
}
```

I receive no webhook calls when draft is deleted.

But I do receive webhook calls from Docusign when **Envelope is sent** and

- completed
- declined
- voided

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behavior that's described in the other SO post that you've linked to ([Deleted Draft Envelopes have inaccurate status](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41837666/deleted-draft-envelopes-have-inaccurate-status)) is 'by design'.  That is, when a new Envelope is created/saved (but not sent), it's considered a *draft* Envelope and its status will be `created`. If the draft Envelope is subsequently deleted without ever being sent, its status will still be `created` -- there is no distinct status value that indicates a *deleted* draft Envelope.

Since webhooks fire in response to change in Envelope (or Recipient) status, and there is no change in status when a draft Envelope is deleted, you will never receive a webhook notification when a draft Envelope is deleted.

The behavior you've described in your post is 'by design' (as expected) re the event notifications that you've specified and the webhook calls you're receiving in response to the specified Envelope events.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response, I just wanted to double check if that's *by design*. I have one more question about this, but I'm not sure if I should post a new question... If I click to delete draft in DocuSign, I will get message **Deleted envelopes remain in your Deleted bin for only a short time, after which they are removed permanently.**. What happens when envelope draft is removed **permanently**?

Comment: Will webhook fire then?

Comment: There is no change in Envelope *status* that occurs when a draft Envelope gets automatically purged (deleted) from the *Deleted bin* (the Envelope simply ceases to exist), therefore no webhook will fire.

Answer (score 1):

Can you describe your use case whereby you want your software application to be notified when a draft envelope has been deleted?

Comment: Thank you for looking into this! Users create contracts in my application. And then they can create multiple Envelopes and send that to DocuSign (with different signers/recipients, modify generated pdf a bit). So I wanted to track status of those Envelopes from DocuSign, and update status of Envelopes in my application. When Envelope is sent from DocuSign, webhook works and updates status correctly. But when Envelope draft status is changed in DocuSign, I would also like to know that and update Envelopes in my application. So I can stop them from doing actions on those Envelopes.

Comment: Should I create a new question and describe what I'm trying to do?

Comment: I believe I understand: you want a notification when a user deletes a draft envelope by using the DocuSign Web tool. We don't have that now. I've added it to the enhancements list. We won't have it anytime soon. For more discussion of your use case and possible solutions, please file another question. Thanks. @ljubadr

Comment: Yes, that's my case. Notification would make things a bit easier. But I guess I'll  handle DocuSign api error and update my side if that happens. Thank you for the information!